# Goで別のファイルの関数をmainで使いたいのに使えない。

Tags: go

Go言語で別のファイルに書いた関数をmain.goで使いたいが使えません。

cannot find package "helper" in any of:
usr/local/go/src/helper (from $GOROOT)
Users/name/Documents/Go/src/helper (from $GOPATH)

というメッセージが出ます。

```
//Documents/Go/src/leetcode
package main

import (
    "helper"
)

func main() {
    helper.Reverse()
}
```

と

```
//Documents/Go/src/leetcode/helper
package helper

import (
    "fmt"
)

//Reverse prints hello
func Reverse() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

です。helpersの中でたくさん関数を書いてrunするときはmain.goで呼ぶだけという形にしたいのです。
ちなみにGOPATHに問題があるのかと思いTerminalでecho $GOPATHすると
Users/name/Documents/Goでした。
何が問題なのでしょうか？

Comment: `$GOPATH/src` 内の `leetcode` ディレクトリにある `helper` パッケージですので、`import helper "leetcode"` と書くと良いかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import したいパッケージは `$GOPATH/src/leetcode/helper` にあるので、

```
import "leetcode/helper"
```

と書くと良いです。

Comment: echo $GOPATHはUsers/name/Documents/Goになる場合、
importするパッケージもDocuments/Goの中に保存する必要がありますか？

Comment: 今回の場合は、はい、`$GOPATH/src` 以下にソースコードを置くことになります。そうしないと import するパッケージが一意に定まらないかもしれないことに注意してください。英語になりますが "How to Write Go Code" の ["Import paths"](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportPaths) が考え方を知る参考になるかもしれません。